# ssh access to remote server without password - Windows

Tags: linux, windows, ssh, passwords

I transfer files from local machine (windows 7) to remote server (linux) the command line scp , but every time i have to write the password .

Is there a way to configure my machine ( windows) and remote server to accept my transfers without typing password every time. but only for this machine?

Thank you so much

Comment: use ssh certificates on the client PC and the server and you can do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ssh` keys. There is [a lot of tutorials](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-ssh-keys--2) how to set them up. In short:

```
$ ssh-keygen
```

Comment: Thank you I will try that today .

thank you for your disponibility and support